# MonoTouch linker fails to resolve System.Void System.Console::set_ForegroundColor(System.ConsoleColor)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, jit, aot

My app builds/links/deploys fine to the simulator, but I just tried to build/deploy the app to a real device for the first time, and I get a linker failure.

I don't use `System.Console` or `ConsoleColor` anywhere in my app, but I do have a fair amount of code that uses `UIColor`, and I wonder if there's some MT dependency here.

I'm using the latest stuff - MonoDevelop 2.8.6.5 and MonoTouch 5.2.5.

> Compiling to native code /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch -sdkroot
>   "/Developer" -v --nomanifest --nosign -dev
>   "/Users/ogazitt/zaplify/bin/iPhone/Debug/iphone.app" -r
>   "/Users/ogazitt/zaplify/bin/iPhone/Debug/BuiltSteady.Zaplify.Devices.ClientEntities.dll"
>   -r "/Users/ogazitt/zaplify/bin/iPhone/Debug/Utilities.dll" -r "/Users/ogazitt/zaplify/bin/iPhone/Debug/BuiltSteady.Zaplify.Devices.ClientViewModels.dll"
>   -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll" -r "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll" -r
>   "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll" -r
>   "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll" -r
>   "/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/MonoTouch.Dialog-1.dll" -debug
>   -profiling -linksdkonly -sdk "5.0" "/Users/ogazitt/zaplify/bin/iPhone/Debug/zaplifyiphone.exe" MonoTouch
>   version 5.2.5 using framework:
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk
>   Copied /Users/ogazitt/zaplify/bin/iPhone/Debug/zaplifyiphone.exe to
>   /Users/ogazitt/zaplify/bin/iPhone/Debug/iphone.app/zaplifyiphone.exe
>   Copied /Users/ogazitt/zaplify/bin/iPhone/Debug/SharpCompress.3.5.dll
>   to
>   /Users/ogazitt/zaplify/bin/iPhone/Debug/iphone.app/SharpCompress.3.5.dll
>   Copied
>   /Users/ogazitt/zaplify/bin/iPhone/Debug/Newtonsoft.Json.MonoTouch.dll
>   to
>   /Users/ogazitt/zaplify/bin/iPhone/Debug/iphone.app/Newtonsoft.Json.MonoTouch.dll
>   Linking SDK only for assembly
>   /Users/ogazitt/zaplify/bin/iPhone/Debug/zaplifyiphone.exe into
>   /Users/ogazitt/zaplify/bin/iPhone/Debug/iphone.app error MT2002: Can
>   not resolve reference: System.Void
>   System.Console::set_ForegroundColor(System.ConsoleColor)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's very likely that one of your assembly dependencies that contains a reference to both `System.Console.ForegroundColor` property and `System.ConsoleColor` type.

This works under the simulator because the JIT (just in time) compiler is used in this case (faster builds) and, if the execution never reach the `ConsoleColor` code, then you'll never see it's missing from MonoTouch's `mscorlib.dll`.

However when you build for device MonoTouch needs to use the AOT (ahead of time) compiler (because Apple does **not** allow JIT'ing on iOS devices). This means everything (even if you would not use it at execution time) needs to be compiled to native code. Anything missing, like `ConsoleColor`, will result in an error.

If you're unsure which assembly has the reference just open a bug report an attach every .dll and your .exe (you can mark the attachment as **private**) and we'll help you identify the assembly.

Comment: Thanks (once more) Sebastien!  By examining my dependencies in the Assembly Browser I realized that one of my dependencies (SharpCompress) had unresolved references to System, System.Core, and mscorlib; when I removed the dependency, the issue went away.  I guess my question is - for a .NET assembly to work properly with the AOT compiler, does it always need to be compiled against the MT assembly references?

Comment: Not *always* (in theory) but close enough to 100% (in practice) to say that *always* recompiling is **the** solution :-)